# VHDL Selection machine error in port map

Tags: vhdl

I get this error:

```
# Error: COMP96_0100: data_reg.vhd : (156, 35): Actual parameter type in port map does not match the port formal type "Allin".
# Error: COMP96_0100: data_reg.vhd : (158, 1): Actual parameter type in port map does not match the port formal type "Fout".
# Error: COMP96_0100: data_reg.vhd : (162, 1): Actual parameter type in port map does not match the port formal type "D".
# Error: COMP96_0100: data_reg.vhd : (163, 1): Actual parameter type in port map does not match the port formal type "Q".
```

I need some help, please.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity ticket1 is
    port (
        A, B : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Clock: in std_logic;
        O: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture Ticketmachine of ticket1 is  

component ticket_selection 
    port(
        Allin:in bit_vector(3 downto 0);
        Clk: in std_logic;
        Fout: out bit_vector(7 downto 0));  
end component ticket_selection;

component  reg is  
    port(
        C: in std_logic;  
        D: in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
        Q : out bit_vector(7 downto 0));  
end component reg;        

component  Money is
    port (
        Ai,Bi : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        Fo: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end component money;

    signal s1,s2: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin 
    Option: ticket_selection
        port map(
            Allin=>A,
            Clk=>Clock,    
            Fout=>s1);

    Cash: reg
        port map(
            C=>Clock,
            D=>B,
            Q=>s2);

    Pros: Money
        port map(
            Ai=>s1,
            Bi=>s2,
            Fo=>O);
 end architecture;
```

Comment: std_logic_vector is not bit_vector

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2009 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1 General para 13 (in part) *The type of the actual (after applying the conversion function or type conversion, if present in the actual part) shall be the same as the type of the corresponding formal, ...*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. HEre we can help you with you coding issues. But to do that, you need to ask the question properly. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to do that. You only provide us with part of your code, which makes it difficult for us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should read carefully some VHDL guide for beginners. I can't recommend any (maybe someone could?), so I'll go straight to your mistakes here:

1. Never use `std_logic_unsigned`, `std_logic_unsigned`, and `std_logic_arith`. This libraries are not part of standard, and can be replaced with `numeric_std`.
2. Don't use `bit` or `bit_vector` type. Use `std_logic`, and `std_logic_vector` instead.
3. When you associate one vector to other, they must have equal type and length, as user1155120 and Brian Drummond wrote in comment. In particular, you can't assign `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` to `bit_vector(3 downto 0)`.

There are probably more things done wrong here, but your question is not complete - you didn't provide any explanation what it should do, no full code, and no testbench.