# 4bit transfer using synchronous d flip-flop( transfer 4bit from register a to register b)

Tags: vhdl, quartus

When I run this code two errors appear that say "Actual parameter type in port map does not match the type of the formal port 's'. I need help to understand how to fix these.

```
-- code that try in EDA playground to transfer from one register to another 

 -- library 
 library ieee;
 use ieee. std_logic_1164.all;


 -- declaration for d flip-flop
 entity D_FF is
 PORT( D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
       s :in std_logic; 
       CLOCK: in std_logic;
       Q: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
  end D_FF;

 architecture behavioral of D_FF is
 -- signals declaration
 signal s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8: std_logic;
 begin

 --transfer the 4 bit to another register
s1 <= D(0) and (not s);
Q(0) <= s and D(0);
s2 <= D(1) and (not s);
Q(1) <= (Q(0)and s) or s2;
s3 <= D(2) and (not s);
Q(2) <= (Q(1)and s) or s3;
s4 <= D(3) and not s;
Q(3) <= (Q(2)and s)or s4;
s5 <= D(4) and not s;
Q(4) <= (Q(3)and s)or s5;
s6 <= D(5) and not s;
Q(5) <= (Q(4)and s)or s6;
s7 <= D(6) and not s;
Q(6) <= (Q(5)and s)or s7;
s8 <= D(7) and not s;
Q(7) <= (Q(6)and s)or s8;

end behavioral;

 ------------------------------
-- testbench
 ------------------------------
 -- library
library ieee;
use ieee. std_logic_1164.all;


entity testbench is 
-- empty entity
end testbench;
-----------------------------
architecture tb of testbench is -- testbench 
-- architecture  -- REDUNDANT transcription error?
 -- component declaration
 component D_FF is
 PORT( D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
       s :in std_logic;
       CLOCK: in std_logic;
       Q: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
  end component;

  -- signals that need in testbench -- COMMENT DELIMITER transcription error?
  signal D_s: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);-- signals for entity i/o
  signal Q_s: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);-- signals for entity i/o
  signal s_s: std_logic;
  signal CLOCK_s: std_logic;
  -- is the signal that must be run 4 time to transfer the bit 
  signal loop_count: integer;
   begin

  dut:D_FF port map(D_s,Q_s,s_s,CLOCK_s);   
  -- design under test instantiation

 stimProcess: process                                           -- 
 --stimulus generator
  begin
    --the run 4 time this to transfer the 4 bit 
    for loop_counter in 0 to 3 loop
    D_s <= "01100000";
    wait until CLOCK_s = '1' and CLOCK_s'event;
    end loop;

  end process stimProcess;                                  
  -- without sensitivity list
  end tb;
```

Comment: ` dut: D_FF port map (D_s,Q_s,s_s,CLOCK_s);` has positional port association  of signals of std_logic_vector, std_logic_vector, std_logic, std_logic while the order shown in the D_FF component declaration is std_logic_vector, std_logic, std_logic, std_logic_vector. Either use formal association or correct the association order for dut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL Selection machine error in port map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956607/vhdl-selection-machine-error-in-port-map)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that replicates the problem and includes complete error messages.

Comment: EEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.1 General para 13 (in part) "The type of the actual (after applying the conversion function or type conversion, if present in the actual part) shall be the same as the type of the corresponding formal, "...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a positional association for the port map. When you do this, the order of ports in your port map must match the order of ports in your component declaration. Using positional association, the proper order is:

```vhdl
dut:D_FF port map(D_s,s_s,CLOCK_s,Q_s);
```

Note that in your example, you've connected the signal `Q_s` to `s`, `s_s` to `CLOCK`, and `CLOCK_s` to `Q` (because your order was not the same).

I always prefer named association. On the left, you have your "formal" (the port outlined in your component declaration). On the right, you have the "actual" (the signal you're connecting to that port). The whitespace is just to improve readability.

```vhdl
dut: D_FF 
  port map (
    D     => D_s,
    s     => s_s,
    CLOCK => CLOCK_s,
    Q     => Q_s
  );
```

Named association port maps are much easier to debug, and the ports can be mapped in any order.

Comment: thanks kevin  is run now put the output is not that i expect. i expect if my D is =01100000 then tou must be appear like this D=00000110 you can help me on that please ??. -user6411653

Comment: entity D_FF is
 PORT( D : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
       s :in std_logic; 
       CLOCK: in std_logic;
       Q: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
  end D_FF;

 architecture behavioral of D_FF is
 -- signals declaration
 --signal s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8: std_logic;
 begin

Comment: --transfer the 4 bit to another register
d_ff: entity work.D_FF port map(D(0),CLOCK,Q(0));
d_ff1: entity work.D_FF port map(D(1),CLOCK,Q(2));
d_ff2: entity work.D_FF port map(D(2),CLOCK,Q(2));
d_ff3: entity work.D_FF port map(D(3),CLOCK,Q(3));
d_ff4: entity work.D_FF port map(D(4),CLOCK,Q(4));
d_ff5: entity work.D_FF port map(D(5),CLOCK,Q(5));
d_ff6: entity work.D_FF port map(D(6),CLOCK,Q(6));
d_ff7: entity work.D_FF port map(D(7),CLOCK,Q(7));

process(CLOCK,D,s)
begin 
 if s ='1' then 
     Q<=D;
    end if;
end process;
end behavioral;

Comment: this is the code that i try now put is appear some errors.    COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0100: "Actual parameter type in port map does not match the type of the formal port 'D'." "design.vhd" 20 33 this is the error for all D that i put in d_ff port map

Comment: please help me to understand how to solve this exercise

Comment: @sofronis if you have a new issue, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It is very difficult to read code posted in comments, but I can already see you are not taking proper care in your port maps.